# LINQ: Fill List<ViewModel> with properties from 2 different models

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List with ID and Name that I want to fill with properties from two other lists.

```
List<Foo> foolist = foo.fromdatasource(); // for all items in this list
List<Bar> = barlist from bar.datasource(); // fill a new list with Name property from this list

List<ViewModel> viewModel = new List<ViewModel>();

foreach (Foo foo in foolist)
{
   viewmodel.Add(new ViewModel
   {
      Id = foo.Id
      Name = barlist.Where(f => f.Id == b.Id).Select(s => s.Name)
   });
}
```

That last line doesn't give me the name from the item from barlist corresponding to the id from foolist. Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Comment: `.Select(s => s.Name)` will return a collection of anonymous objects with a `Name` property. You want to use Count Les solution. On a side note, read up on "access to modified closure" (I assume you meant `f.Id == foo.Id`).

Comment: @alexn: Are you sure it would return a collection of anon. objects with a `Name` property? I think it should return a collection of `String`s, or whatever the type of `Name` is.

Comment: @BorisB. You are right of course, my bad :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your last line with below line:

```
Name = barlist.First(f => f.Id == b.Id).Name;
```

For more constraint to avoid `null` exception, you can write:

```
var viewModels = foo.Select(f => {
    var bar = barlist.FirstOrDefault(b => f.Id == b.Id);

    return new ViewModel() { 
        Id = f.Id, 
        Name = bar == null? null : bar.Name 
    };
});
```

You also can use the method `SingleOrDefault` instead of `FirstOrDefault`, it's the same result since I guess your `Id` is unique

Comment: The would be a performance difference between `FirstOrDefault` and `SingleOrDefault`, because the second one iterates through entire collection every time it's used when `FirstOrDefault` returns the element as soon as it is found.

Comment: hi Cuong, your first suggestion indeed gives me "Sequence contains no matching element", but your second answer indeed did the trick. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What is `b` or `b.ID`?

If it is something and you want to use it then

```
Name = barlist.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == foo.Id).Name;
```

otherwise

```
Name = barlist.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == b.Id).Name;
```